# Question about the norm $\|A \cdot \|_1$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces

$A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$, where $n > m$, has independent columns. Consider the vector norm $\| x \|_\Box = \| A x \|_1$. Consider two matrices $M_1$, $M_2$ which preserve this norm, i.e. $\forall i \in \{1,2\}. \| M_i x \|_\Box = \| M_i x \|_\Box$.

Consider the matrix $M_c$ which has the property that its i-th row is either the i-th row of $M_1$ or $M_2$.

Is there a vector norm which is preserved by $M_c$? If not, is there a vector norm with respect to which $M_c$ is non-expansive? If not, is there a sub-multiplicative matrix norm $\| \cdot \|_{S}$ for which $\| M_c \|_{S} \leq 1$?